# What kind of item is this?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I found an item that doesn't look like the other stuff in my valuables tab.

[image]

As you can see, it's red and shadowy and it has a description that makes me feel like it's important. I've been hanging on to it since I found it just in case but so far, I've come up with nothing. Is this just another thing I can sell or does it have some kind of purpose? Are there other items like this to be found?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from my experience, this icon stands for unique items, essentially items that you will acquire only once. The utility of these items vary wildly. One of these items, Sad Splinters, is needed to acquire a schematic while Too Many Breeches (picked up during Sera's recruitment) still doesn't, to my knowledge, have an actual gameplay use.

I would advocate caution when it comes to dealing with these items, but unfortunately as of 2014/11/29, DAI does not yet have a storage mechanic so inventory space comes at a premium.

Comment: Do these get automatically sold, if you press "sell all" in valuables?

Comment: @cbirdsong Yes, everything in the valuables tab gets sold, including all creature research items.